# CakePHP Croogo CMS How to remove "page" and "blog" from the URL?

Tags: cakephp, content-management-system

I'm using `CakePHP CMS` named [Croogo](http://croogo.org/). I've customized my theme and also created most of the pages.

But I've got a new requirement to remove the `page` and `blog` from the URL. Either one will be ok. I've created all the static content of my site as `page` for every url is coming with `page/slug`.

How to remove this from the URL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've tried this in my `'croogo_routes.php'` file and it worked like charm.

After doing this my pages are working with both way like `'page/slug'` and `'slug'`

```
CroogoRouter::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'view', 'type' => 'page', 'slug' => ':slug'));
```

Includes this line in pages section. Like this

```
// Page
    CroogoRouter::connect('/:slug', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'view', 'type' => 'page', 'slug' => ':slug'));
    CroogoRouter::connect('/about', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'view', 'type' => 'page', 'slug' => 'about'));
    CroogoRouter::connect('/page/:slug', array('controller' => 'nodes', 'action' => 'view', 'type' => 'page'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `routes` to define your mapping from urls to controller/actions.

See this book article for more about routes: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/945/Routes-Configuration

If you find that that does not work for you, consider using [Custom Route Classes](http://mark-story.com/posts/view/using-custom-route-classes-in-cakephp)